# Deleting controls each time ShowDialog is called

Tags: vb.net, showdialog, control-array

I have a form that I display exclusively with the `ShowDialog` method. In the `Form_Shown` event, I dynamically create a set of labels and text boxes based on a public variable set in the form making the call.

I understand that the form is not closed or destroyed but simply hidden between calls, and as such I added code at the top of my `Form_Shown` event to clear out any controls from a previous call, but the controls aren't being removed. I have tried `ctrl.Dispose` (as in the code below) and `Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)`. Neither produces an error, but the Textboxes are not removed and new ones are created over them. (For some reason,

This is the first time I've dynamically created/removed controls in .NET, so it's possible my yearning for VB6's control arrays have something to do with the error.

The form builds itself based on the calling form's public ListView variable. The calling form makes certain this variable is not nothing and that items are selected if and only if the user is editing an existing row.

```
Public Class frmTableEdit

Private isNew As Boolean
Private inputText() As TextBox

Private Sub FormTableEdit_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is TextBox Or TypeOf (ctrl) Is Label Then
            ctrl.Dispose()
        End If
    Next
    With frmKioskData.TBLobj
        Dim fieldCount As Integer = .Columns.Count - 1
        isNew = .SelectedIndices.Count = 0

        '(code setting size of form and location of OK/Cancel buttons is here)

        ReDim inputText(fieldCount)
        For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount
            Dim lbl As New Label, txt As New TextBox
            inputText(i) = txt
            Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Me.Controls.Add(txt)

            '(code setting size and and position of lbl & txt is here)

            'lbl.Tag = i    (I commented these lines out because I never used the 
            'txt.Tag = i    Tag property, but can if a solution calls for it.)

            lbl.Text = .Columns(i).Text
            If isNew Then
                txt.Text = ""
            Else
                txt.Text = .Items(.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(i).Text
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You might be messing with the default instance.  Why does the top loop use `Me` but later you use `frmKioskData` are they the same thing?  The code to show the dialog might help.

Comment: @Plutonix, they are not the same; `frmKioskData` is the calling form. I'm not at my computer at the moment to get the exact code but I can tell you that I use `frmTableEdit.ShowDialog()` rather than declaring a variable as a new form. I do know from debugging that, whether this is the default or not, I'm getting the same instance each call (as expected) and that the `Shown` event is firing each time (also as expected). I suspected the problem was with `Dispose` because `Me.Controls.Count` grows with each successive call.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `inputText()` array?  Storing an additional reference to the TextBox controls will prevent them from being disposed of.  If you use an explicit form reference and put the disposal loop in `Sub Dispose(bool disposing)` they should clean up fine

Comment: `inputText()` exists so that I can refer to each TextBox by index in a separate event. But thanks for the tip about the extra reference preventing disposal @Plutonix; I didn't know that (though of course now it seems obvious) and I strongly suspect this is the cause of my problem. I'll update in the morning.

Comment: you dont need an array of control references for that, just control *names* in a `List(of String)` give them names like `"tbNumber_" & i.ToString()` and use the names to refer to them in the Controls collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @Plutonix's suggestion in the comment above does not quite work for you, I think it would be easiest and make more sense to dispose of the form after calling ShowDialog, and then when you need to show that form you create a new instance with a parameter that tells it what dynamic controls to load.

So you'd have a New method in frmTableEdit that uses this parameter:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal fieldCount As Integer)
        InitializeComponent()
        fieldCount = fieldCount  'Where fieldCount is a class variable
End Sub
```

And when you call this form from frmKioskData, you can do so like this:

```
Dim newTableEdit As New frmTableEdit(Me.TBLobj.Columns.Count - 1)
newTableEdit.ShowDialog()
newTableEdit.Dispose()
```

Then the code in your frmEditTable's Shown event just simply has to add the controls accordingly, without the need to remove old ones:

```
ReDim inputText(fieldCount)
For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount
    Dim lbl As New Label, txt As New TextBox
    inputText(i) = txt
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)

    '(code setting size and and position of lbl & txt is here)

    'lbl.Tag = i    (I commented these lines out because I never used the 
    'txt.Tag = i    Tag property, but can if a solution calls for it.)

    lbl.Text = .Columns(i).Text
    If isNew Then
        txt.Text = ""
    Else
        txt.Text = .Items(.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(i).Text
    End If
Next
```

How you get the isNew value is up to you - you can add that as a second parameter to the form's New, or get it the same way you are now...w/e.  If it were me I'd normally add that as another New parameter.

Comment: This general approach worked for me. I was still having the same problem after releasing the extra reference (`inputText`). After tweaking this a bit (mostly because my code needs the entire `ListView` object, not just `Columns.Count`), things are working fine.